# Can an object be visible in another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Getting grips with Obj-C as time goes on which is good!

So, I will use my example I'm trying to learn from. I am using tabbed view controllers. I have a UIButton on the page which brings up a new view like this:

```
FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

self.filterViewController = ctrl;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.filterViewController animated:NO];
```

Now, let's say I create a class called TimeFilter and I init it in the FirstViewController

```
TimeFilter *timeFilter = [[TimeFilter alloc] init];
[timeFilter saveTime:1300];
```

In FilterViewController can I just do this:

```
int timeSelected;
timeSelected = [timeFilter getTime];
```

I am trying to get my head around how objects work in a application as opposed to Command Line Tool.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a property in the `FilterViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) timeFilter;
```

Then you can assign the `timeFilter` in your view controller to the `FilterViewController` before presenting it:

```
TimeFilter *myTimeFilter = [[TimeFilter alloc] init];
[myTimeFilter saveTime:1300];
FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];
ctrl.timeFilter = myTimeFilter;
```

Then inside FilterViewController you can do:

```
int timeSelected = [self.timeFilter getTime];
```

And don't use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` to show your new view controller. The correct way to achieve what you want is:

```
ctrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentViewController:ctrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hey, sorry! This has lost me. So, is getTime still defined in the class TimeFilter, like `int theTime; -(int)getTime{ return theTime; }`

Comment: @JoshBoothe yes `getTime` is defined in TimeFilter. You don't have to change that class. A property is like pointer with automated getter/setter methods and memory management. You are basically telling the FilterViewController class which TimeFilter instance to use.

Comment: I think I'm getting a bit closer. So I have created the class TimeFilter, created a property in the FirstViewController.h file, I have `#import`ed the TimeFilter.h file in both .h and .m for FilterViewController, so I assume now I have to import the TimeFilter.h in my FilterViewController (the view that pops up on the screen) and then do `[timeFilter setTime:1];` and in FirstViewController it will be accessible via `timeFilter.getTime` is that correct? Thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 2):

Yes u can do things like this and u have to ways:

1) You can make those methods -class method, so, u will not need to create objects.

```
+(id)getTime
```

and call it from any place

```
[TimeFilter getTime];
```

2) You can make TimeFilter a singleton

```
+(TimeFilter*)shared
{
   static TimeFilter *kTimeFilter = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    kTimeFilter = [TimeFilter new];
});   
   return kTimeFilter;
}
```

and in any place of your code call

```
[[TimeFilter shared] getTime];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I haven't got to singletons in my book (Programming in Objective-C, 5th edition) yet, so I will try the first one! So as long as the class is included at the top of the file it will be accessible via the class method in all views is that correct? So, changing views the data stays the same inside the class / object?

Comment: If you create a singleton, you need to make it thread safe through dispatch_once